# Read and Write text file using create-react-app from the browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, browser

I am trying to read a text file that is in the source(src) folder of the react project(creat-react-app), manipulate the values and write back the new value to the same text file.

I am unable to read the values from the file, even though the code that reads the file is logging out old data, not sure where is that coming from. Because even if change the data in the text file directly, it doesn't read the new value.

I am using a package called browserify-fs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs) for reading and writing to a file.

```js
var fs = require('browserify-fs');
var reader = new FileReader();  


export const getData = () => {
let initialString = "abcd";
  fs.readFile('file.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
       return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(initialString + data.toString());
 });
};

export const writeData = () => {
    let data = "abcd";
    fs.writeFile("file.txt", data, err => {
      // In case of a error throw err.
      if (err) throw err;
    });
}
```

Does it have to do something with webpack-loader for importing the types of file for the build or is it related specifically to create-react-app package which defines the files and folder structure for auto-importing types of files?

I am still not sure what is the actual issue causing. Any help would be appreciated.

**P.S: I know using CRUD operations on the browser is not a recommended practice, just using for a personal project(learning purpose).**